# GMRES Residuals

Tags: math, iteration

I'm trying to write a code that solves Ax=b with the GMRES Method and gives the residual vectors. I found a way to do it on stackoverflow but it just gives n values (n 1-dim vectors or one n-dim vector?) (n=dimension of A). How can I fix that? It's also important to note that I haven't used python in 5 years so I might be missing something obvious.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import gmres
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class gmres_counter(object):
    def __init__(self, disp=True):
        self._disp = disp
        self.niter = 0
        self.callbacks = []
        self.internal_list = []
    def append(elem):
        self.internal_list.append(elem)
    def getList(self):
        return self.internal_list
    def __call__(self, rk=None):
       self.callbacks.append(rk)
       self.internal_list.append(rk)
       self.niter += 1


n=14
P = np.random.normal(size=[n, n])
b = np.ones(n)

counter = gmres_counter()
x, info = gmres(P, b, callback=counter)

ylist=counter.getList()
print(ylist)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm spotted one problem with the `append` method in your `gmres_counter` class: it should have `self` as the first argument.

```
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75929238/gmres-residuals

import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy.linalg import solve
from scipy.sparse.linalg import gmres

class gmres_counter(object):
    def __init__(self, disp=True):
        self._disp = disp
        self.niter = 0
        self.callbacks = []
        self.internal_list = []
    def append(self, elem):
        self.internal_list.append(elem)
    def getList(self):
        return self.internal_list
    def __call__(self, rk=None):
       self.callbacks.append(rk)
       self.internal_list.append(rk)
       self.niter += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n=14
    P = np.random.normal(size=[n, n])
    b = np.ones(n)

    counter = gmres_counter()
    x, info = gmres(P, b, callback=counter)

    ylist = counter.getList()
    print('GMRES Solution')
    print('x    : ', x)
    print('resid: ', ylist)

    x_solve = solve(P, b)
    print('LU solution')
    print('x    : ', x_solve)


    # https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/basic/plot.html
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(range(counter.niter), ylist, linewidth=2)
    ax.set(xlim=(0, counter.niter), xticks=np.arange(1, counter.niter),  ylim=(0, 1.0),           yticks=np.arange(0.1, 1.0, 0.1))
    plt.xlabel('Iteration')
    plt.ylabel('Residual L2 Norm')
    plt.show()
```

I added an LU decomposition solver and re-ran your code.  It got the same result as the GM res solver, as it should.  I've printed the solution and residuals:

```
GMRES Solution
x    :  [-0.04836504 -0.19883297 -0.76133017 -0.1105711   0.13153163  0.71358906
  0.07695915 -0.00164183 -0.48687419 -0.68267705 -0.13558068  1.52739484
  0.05131082 -0.10846915]
resid:  [0.9924651825977392, 0.9891836835446075, 0.9849547027113549, 0.9279580685675294, 0.8898026906905545, 0.834116621182853, 0.8192176931233773, 0.8176278745080459, 0.7994876685920552, 0.5319105164882216, 0.3823627118445627, 0.3462861093994175, 0.030945497524788302, 7.309843014037277e-16]
LU solution
x    :  [-0.04836504 -0.19883297 -0.76133017 -0.1105711   0.13153163  0.71358906
  0.07695915 -0.00164183 -0.48687419 -0.68267705 -0.13558068  1.52739484
  0.05131082 -0.10846915]
```

If I plot residual versus iteration number it shows how your solver converged:

[image]

I skimmed [this article](https://acme.byu.edu/0000017a-1bb8-db63-a97e-7bfa0be30000/vol1lab23gmres-pdf) about GMRES.  Very interesting.  I'm not sure what the issue is, but I appreciate learning about it.

Comment: Well, shouldn't the residuals be vectors instead of numbers? Or are the values in the residual matrix the norms of the residual vectors?

Comment: I think the residual is a vector.  One component per row.

Comment: Are you arguing that residuals should be a 2nd order tensor?  The NumPy solution disagrees with you.

Comment: The residual should be an n-dim vector right? Now after every iteration there is another residual (r_k=b-Ax_k). Hence we expect as many n-dim vectors as there are iterations. In this case a maximum of 14 n-dim residual vectors are needed and their norm needs to approach zero. What get from the code here is only one vector (since the values of the vector tend to zero I presume its actually n 1-dim vectors).

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying now.  You are thinking about your gmres_counter class.  You want to take the residual at the end of each iteration and store it in internal_list.  I'll set a breakpoint in that method and see what's happening.  That's the best way to understand when code fails to match your expectations.

Comment: The residual value rk coming into your __call__ method is a single float64, not a vector.  You are appending one single value at a time into the list to create a list that is as long as your # of iterations.

Comment: It looks like the L2 norm of the residual is being saved, not the complete vector.